# Entity framework, Data annotations [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] and sequential GUID

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, metadata, guid, uniqueidentifier

I'm trying to use the entity framework to communicate with my existing DB. This is thus DB first. Using sql server and c#. The problem is that I would like to use a sequential GUID, generated by the database.

Each time I run the code, my controller pastes the GUID assigned to lutRoughagePhysicalSiloId to the DB (most of the time lutRoughagePhysicalSiloId is just an empty GUID (000..) since I don't fill it). As far as I can see, this should not be happening since I use [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)].

Any Ideas?

SQL code

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[lutRoughagePhysicalSiloType]
(
    [RoughagePhysicalSiloTypeId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY     UNIQUE DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID(),
    [PhysicalSiloTypeName] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE
)
```

(Notice the Default value newsequentialId() that gets generated as default by sql server)

Automatic created modelview (DB first):

```
namespace guiIlvoDairyCowBarn.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class lutConcentratePhysicalSiloType
{
    public lutConcentratePhysicalSiloType()
    {
        this.lutConcentratePhysicalSiloes = new HashSet<lutConcentratePhysicalSilo>();
    }

    public System.Guid ConcentratePhysicalSiloTypeId { get; set; }
    public string PhysicalSiloTypeName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<lutConcentratePhysicalSilo> lutConcentratePhysicalSiloes { get; set; }
}
}
```

Buddy class

```
namespace guiIlvoDairyCowBarn.Models
{
[MetadataType(typeof(lutRoughagePhysicalSiloMD))]
public partial class lutRoughagePhysicalSiloType
{
    public class lutRoughagePhysicalSiloMD
    {

        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public System.Guid RoughagePhysicalSiloTypeId { get; set; }

        [Required, DisplayName("Physical silo type")]
        public string PhysicalSiloTypeName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<lutRoughagePhysicalSilo> lutRoughagePhysicalSiloes { get; set; }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what is a Buddy class suppose to mean?

Using both `[Key]` and the `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` should work and ignore any user provided value.  After saving to the DB the property should have the DB generated Guid.

Your class `lutConcentratePhysicalSiloType` has no EF data annotations and if saved would take the values you provided.  `NewSequentialId()` is a default and without any EF data annotations the DB row will get whatever the value you specify in the C# class.